# VBA If statement inside for loop is not evaluating true

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a macro that's using a multidimensional array to hold several columns of data. The macro then places the array values in a new workbook. Everything works fine except for one if statement. Here's the subroutine whith the if statement

```
Sub push(toWorkbook As Workbook, ByRef code() As Variant)
'activeBook = "TempEDI.xlsm"

'Workbooks(activeBook).Activate 'set new workbook as active book
Dim newSheet As Worksheet
Set newSheet = toWorkbook.Sheets(1)
h = 2
f = 0
g = 0
newSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Customer"
newSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Invoice #"
newSheet.Cells(1, 6).Value = "ASN"
For i = 0 To UBound(code)
    newSheet.Cells(h, 1).Value = code(i, 0)
    newSheet.Cells(h, 2).Value = code(i, 1)
    If code(f, 2) = code(i, 1) Then
        newSheet.Cells(h, 6).Value = code(f, 2)
        f = f + 1
    End If
    If code(g, 3) = code(i, 1) Then '****** <--- THIS IS THE STATEMENT 
        newSheet.Cells(h, 3).Value = code(g, 3)
        newSheet.Cells(h, 4).Value = code(g, 4)
        newSheet.Cells(h, 5).Value = code(g, 5)
        g = g + 1
    End If
    h = h + 1
Next i
MsgBox code(g, 3) & " " & code(g, 1)
End Sub
```

See, my first if statement works as it should, but the second never evaluates to true, even though I know for a fact that code(0,3) = code(0,1). I even put a MsgBox at the end of the subroutine to spit both values out and they are the same. Any idea what's going on? why this statement never evaluates to true? Any help, ideas, or pointers appreciated,. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the two values *exactly* the same? Could one have an extra space (`"text"` vs `"text "`) or different capitalization? (`"Text"` vs `"text"`)?

Comment: Bridging off @cybernetic.nomad's comment, maybe try `If Trim(code(g, 3)) = Trim(code(i, 1)) Then`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad you called it, thanks.

Comment: @dwirony using trim now and it works beautifully thanks for telling me about Trim()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @cybernetic.nomad 
There was white-space in code(0,3). The solution is as @dwirony said, to use the trim function like so

`If Trim(code(g, 3)) = Trim(code(i, 1)).`
For peace of mind I recommend using trim on anything involving data at risk of having unknown white-space. 
Updated code using trim here:

```
Sub push(toWorkbook As Workbook, ByRef code() As Variant)
'activeBook = "TempEDI.xlsm"

'Workbooks(activeBook).Activate 'set new workbook as active book
Dim newSheet As Worksheet
Set newSheet = toWorkbook.Sheets(1)
h = 2
f = 0
g = 0
newSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Customer"
newSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Invoice #"
newSheet.Cells(1, 6).Value = "ASN"
For i = 0 To UBound(code)
    newSheet.Cells(h, 1).Value = code(i, 0)
    newSheet.Cells(h, 2).Value = code(i, 1)
    If code(f, 2) = code(i, 1) Then
        newSheet.Cells(h, 6).Value = code(f, 2)
        f = f + 1
    End If
    If Trim(code(g, 3)) = Trim(code(i, 1)) Then '****** <--- THIS IS THE STATEMENT 
        newSheet.Cells(h, 3).Value = code(g, 3)
        newSheet.Cells(h, 4).Value = code(g, 4)
        newSheet.Cells(h, 5).Value = code(g, 5)
        g = g + 1
    End If
    h = h + 1
Next i
MsgBox code(g, 3) & " " & code(g, 1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If `code()` is two-dimensional, then try:

```
For i = Lbound(code,1) To UBound(code,1)
```

there may be other problems.